# error when i install larevel using composer in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, composer

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs# composer create-project laravel/laravel sampleApp --prefer-dist



  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL  
   operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:                       
  error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify   
  failed                                                                       
  Failed to enable crypto                                                      
  failed to open stream: operation failed                                      



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [package] [directory] [version]
```

--> please help me for that probel

Answer (score 1):

If you have the latest composer, and work behind a proxy, this worked for me:

```
export http_proxy=http://ip:port
export HTTP_PROXY=http://ip
export https_proxy=
export HTTPS_PROXY=
```